# Left Join in Hibernate, query returns rows only from left table

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have table delegat and table kotizacije_cjenovnik with fk kategorije_id which reference to id columnn of delegat table. I want to join these two tables and return the result. Here's my Delegat class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "delegat")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Delegat implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "delegat_name", nullable = false)

@OneToMany(
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true
)
private List<KotizacijeCjenovnik> kategorija = new ArrayList<>();


private String delegatName;

// jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here, do not remove
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDelegatName() {
    return delegatName;
}

public Delegat delegatName(String delegatName) {
    this.delegatName = delegatName;
    return this;
}

public void setDelegatName(String delegatName) {
    this.delegatName = delegatName;
}
// jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here, do not remove


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    Delegat delegat = (Delegat) o;
    if (delegat.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return Objects.equals(getId(), delegat.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(getId());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Delegat{" +
        "id=" + getId() +
        ", delegatName='" + getDelegatName() + "'" +
        "}";
   }
}
```

And this is KotizacijeCjenovnik class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "kotizacije_cjenovnik")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class KotizacijeCjenovnik implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "cijena1", nullable = false)
private Double cijena1;

@Column(name = "cijena2", nullable = false)
private Double cijena2;

@Column(name = "cijena3", nullable = false)
private Double cijena3;

@ManyToOne
private Delegat kategorija;

@ManyToOne
private Kotizacija kotizacija;

// jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here, do not remove
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Double getCijena1() {
    return cijena1;
}

public KotizacijeCjenovnik cijena1(Double cijena) {
    this.cijena1 = cijena;
    return this;
}

public void setCijena1(Double cijena) {
    this.cijena1 = cijena;
}

public Double getCijena2() {
    return cijena2;
}

public KotizacijeCjenovnik cijena2(Double cijena) {
    this.cijena2 = cijena;
    return this;
}

public void setCijena2(Double cijena) {
    this.cijena2 = cijena;
}

public Double getCijena3() {
    return cijena3;
}

public KotizacijeCjenovnik cijena3(Double cijena) {
    this.cijena3 = cijena;
    return this;
}

public void setCijena3(Double cijena) {
    this.cijena3 = cijena;
}


public Kotizacija getKotizacija() {
    return kotizacija;
}

public KotizacijeCjenovnik kotizacija(Kotizacija kotizacija) {
    this.kotizacija = kotizacija;
    return this;
}

public void setKotizacija(Kotizacija kotizacija) {
    this.kotizacija = kotizacija;
}


public Delegat getDelegat() {
    return kategorija;
}

public KotizacijeCjenovnik delegat(Delegat kategorija) {
    this.kategorija = kategorija;
    return this;
}

public void setDelegat(Delegat kategorija) {
    this.kategorija = kategorija;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    KotizacijeCjenovnik kotizacijeCjenovnik = (KotizacijeCjenovnik) o;
    if(kotizacijeCjenovnik.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return Objects.equals(getId(), kotizacijeCjenovnik.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(getId());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "KotizacijeCjenovnik{" +
        "id=" + getId() +
        ", cijena1=" + getCijena1() +
        ", cijena2=" + getCijena2() +
        ", cijena3=" + getCijena3() +
        "}";
   }
 }
```

And this is a function which to return result:

```
@Query(value="select delegat from Delegat delegat left join fetch delegat.kategorija")
    List<Object> getUnused();
```

But I only get results from Delegat. My question is how to return rows from delegat table, with matching rows from kotizacije_cjenovnik table.

Comment: i don't see any field named kategorija inside Delegat entity

Comment: @Zeromus I've posted old code. I've just edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn around the query and select the many side, simply:

```
@Query(value="select kot from KotizacijeCjenovnik kot")
    List<KotizacijeCjenovnik> getUnused();
```

you got one `KotizacijeCjenovnik` for each row of your query and you can call for each of them `getDelegat` to access the corresponding `Delegat` entity